# Java Generics: Why does an explicit cast cause a compiler error, but variable assignment does not

Tags: java, android

This block compiles properly:

```
ArrayList<Baz> list = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("foo");
bar(list);
```

But this block errors stating that `ArrayList<Parcelable>` can not be cast to `ArrayList<Baz>`:

```
bar((ArrayList<Baz>)savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("foo"))
```

Where bar is of the form:

```
private void bar(ArrayList<Baz> food) {
}
```

And `Baz` is a class that implements the `Parcelable` interface

Is there a way that the direct cast can be done rather than having to perform an implicit cast and create an unnecessary variable?

Comment: What type does savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList() return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the error that you're getting; I would think that you'll only get a warning stating that it is an unchecked cast.  If this is the case, you will need to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to the function that you're FROM.  To be honest; you'd be best to create a separate variable to catch the return value then send the variable.

One of the issues that you'll see here is that Java's type erasure is going to hurt you.  If T is declared differently between calling function and receiving function, when T is removed there is nothing that prevents someone from actually sending your function which expects ArrayList an ArrayList.  Which is why this is a type safety issue.

Comment: As reported by Eclipse:  "Cannot cast from ArrayList<Parcelable> to ArrayList<T>"

Comment: Yes, although you could cast ArrayList<Parcelable> to ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> however ArrayList<ExtensionOfParcelable> to ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> does not.  Which means that Java does not do well with covariance/contravariance.

Comment: Looks like `bar((ArrayList<Baz>)(ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>)savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("foo"))` does the trick although creates a unchecked cast warning. Ugly and not worth saving 1 identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Both those blocks are the same. Take this as an example which compiles:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test<T> {

    public void test(){
        ArrayList<T> list = (ArrayList<T>)foo();
        bar(list);
        bar((ArrayList<T>)foo());
    }
    private ArrayList<Integer> foo(){ return null; }    
    private void bar(ArrayList<T> food) {}  
}
```

Comment: my response was based on a previous version of the question that used T which I thought was a type variable. then it was changed to Baz.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use reference the method `bar(ArrayList<T> food)`, you must perform a *generic type invocation*, which replaces `T` with some concrete value. `T` must be bounded to some type else, introduce wildcards like `bar(ArrayList<?> food)`.

- [Reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html).

Comment: Was using T there as a concrete class. Updated the question to make that clearer.

Comment: For your update, the generic is **bounded** to 'Baz' while you're sending it an ArrayList<Parcelable>. The compiler finds these bounded types incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, and my solution is to create a method to convert Parcelable to Baz.
For example..

```
private ArrayList<Baz> convertParcelableToBaz(ArrayList<Parcelable> parcelableList){
    ArrayList<Baz> bazList= new ArrayList<Baz>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < parcelableList.size(); i++){
        bazList.add((Baz)parcelableList.get(i));
    }
    return bazList;
}
```

so that

```
ArrayList<Baz> list = convertParcelableToBaz(savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("foo"));
```

and no unchecked cast warning.